# The SelectKBest gives the scores as nan values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a data set and I am trying to get the feature importances using `SelectKBest` and `Chi2`, but the `SelectKBest` is giving the scores of the features as `nan`.

The data file and code file are present at [this](https://github.com/MokshithSandeep/DataSet) link

```
# Path to the data file
file_path = r"D:\Data_Sets\Mobile_Prices\data.csv"

# Reading the data from the Southern Second Order file, and also passing the column names to south_data data frame
south_data = pd.read_csv(file_path)


# Printing the number of data points and the number of columns of south_data data frame
print("The number of data points in the data  :", south_data.shape[0])
print("The features of the data :", south_data.shape[1])

# Printing the head of south_data data frame
print(south_data.head())

# Check for the nulls
print(south_data.isnull().sum())

# Separate the x and y
x = south_data.drop("tss", axis = 1)
y = south_data["tss"]

# Find the scores of features
bestfit = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=5)
features = bestfit.fit(x,y)
x_new = features.transform(x)

print(features.scores_)

# The output of features.scores_ is displayed as
# array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the values in your target variable is `1`. That is the reason for `nan` values in your `scores_`. Hence please verify your target variable.

Just for illustration:

```py
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
>>> X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
>>> X.shape
(1797, 64)
>>> feature_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)
>>> X_new = feature_selector.fit_transform(X, np.ones(len(X)) )
>>> feature_selector.scores_
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

Comment: Thanks ai_learning. I have changed my y now and it works.
Thanks again for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

'bestfit' is an object and you don't need to assign a variable to it when calling the fit method. Try:

```
# Find the scores of features
bestfit = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=5)
bestfit.fit(x,y)
x_new = bestfit.transform(x)
print(bestfit.scores_)
```

Alternatively, you can call fit and transform at the same time:

```
# Find the scores of features
bestfit = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=5)
x_new = bestfit.fit_transform(x)
print(bestfit.scores_)
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Matt, i tried both the above mentioned solutions, but , none worked.
The output for both the solutions is given as
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]